# run internal script after external script has been loaded via defer

Tags: javascript, loading

It is well known to everyone that using `defer` is an efficient way to minimize the loading time of a website.

In my project, I am using `Vue` (included in the header using defer) and in a circumstance, I want to use a component that is created by another person. When I try to do `Vue.Component(...)` in the body of the HTML, it says `Vue` is undefined. It seems that my script in the body is running before the external script has been loaded. Is there any way to fix this issue?

I tried to do `document.onload`, but the function itself is not working.

PS: Just to be clear, the external script is referring to my js file where `Vue` is defined and I am not talking about the third party library at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `document.onload` you need to use `window.onload` or `document.body.onload`.

But an even better way is to wait for the [`load` event on `<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) tag:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script id="vue-script" src="vue.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onVueLoaded() {
                Vue.render();
            }

            if ('Vue' in window) {
                onVueLoaded();
            } else {
                var script = document.getElementById('vue-script');
                script.addEventListener('load', onVueLoaded);
                script.addEventListener('error', () => console.warn('failed to load Vue.js'));
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I also added a handler for the [`error` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) if you wanted to explicitly handle loading errors.